# HTAccess and using Date environment variables?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Currently I use a HTAccess set-up to watermark my Gallery images, held in a sub-folders for different photographers, and on all other websites I control:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule \.(jpeg|jpg)$ ../plugins/watermark/watermark.php?text=Copyright+©+2015+My+Site [QSA,NC]
```

To save going and editing each HTAccess file, and remembering to do so, can I use a server environment variable instead to create the required text for the Year?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **`%{TIME_YEAR}`** variable instead of hardcoding year:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule \.jpe?g$ ../plugins/watermark/watermark.php?text=Copyright+©+%{TIME_YEAR}+My+Site [QSA,L,NC]
```